# Why the input[type=radio]'s defalut value is 'on' instead of ''?

Tags: javascript, html

Just show the code:

```js
function show() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[type=radio]').value) // 'on'
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">

<button onclick="show()">Show value</button>
```

Comment: That's the default value for radios and checkboxes, you can explicitly set the value in HTML or by JS/jQ. `<input type="radio" value='"arbitraryValue">`

Answer (score 6):

It's the default value for radio and checkbox input. It does not mean that radio button is currently "on". The property you would want for that is checked.

```html
<input type="radio" value="Another Value">
<script>
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[type=radio]').checked)
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[type=radio]').value) // 'on'
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, radio buttons (like buttons) has the value `on`. You need to specify it by giving the tag an `value` attribute, and very likely a `name` attribute. e.g.

```js
<input type="radio" name="category" value="1">
```

The `name` specifies which group this button belongs to, and `value` specifies which is the meaning of the selected button, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Answer (score 2):

The [MDN page for the `<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) states this simply:

> The default `value` for checkboxes and radio buttons is `on`.

This default makes most sense for checkboxes: if you specify a checkbox named `foo`, then submitting a form with that box ticked sends the server the string `foo=on`. This is more convenient than having it send `foo=`, so the empty string would not be a convenient default.

Since radio buttons are essentially an extension of checkboxes, this default was probably applied to both back when their behaviour was first being designed.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually tries to address the question. The other answers all simply say, "just because".

Comment: @MrLister To be honest, it's a bit unclear what the OP expected to happen, so my answer and Mike Zinn's are kind of answering different interpretations of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because radio input's context as input is that there should always be a selected value.

Its the opposite of checkbox in context, you can opt-out for a value.

Use what's necessary although these defaults can be overridden.